# Destiny: Legendary Edition

Tags: destiny

My public library has a copy of Destiny Legendary Edition with all the previous expansions. However, when I put the disk in the PS4, the areas still say "Requires Taken King" even though the game I took out is that edition. 
One option it gives is to use a redeemeable code. If that redeemeable code is somewhere in the game container, where is it?

Comment: You will not be getting that code, it is one time use

Comment: I recommend buying a code online as this code will have been used by some other lucky person who had it before.

Comment: are there codes online that are cheaper than the price of the full game

Answer (score 1):

So the Taken King is by downloaded/accessible through a code that you enter in to the PS Store. Chances are if you got this from a public library the first person who took the game out was the lucky dog who got the code for free, or the library took the code out. Codes are a one time use, so even if it was in there and the code did not work you would be in the same boat. You will only have access to what the disk gives you.

Comment: where would that code be though

Comment: @user3163829 it would be in the game case on the left side when you opened it. It would be a piece of paper with pictures and a code on it.

Comment: Most libraries often take out "filler" papers inside the DVD cases themselves, so you're most likely out of luck, unfortunately.

Comment: @user3163829 does this fulfill your question? If so, please mark as answer to close it.